# Programmatically deleting user from All People

Tags: 2007, spweb

i am able to remove the user from site collection using in this way:-

```
SPWeb.SiteUsers.Remove("providername:" + this.txtOldName.Text);
```

but found the same user existing in All People how to remove user from All People programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed the issue using

```
oldUser = oWeb.SiteUsers["providername:" + this.txtOldName.Text];
int id = oldUser.ID;
oWeb.SiteUsers.RemoveByID(id);
```

oWeb is the object of SPWeb